# Session not found error using quickfix python?

Tags: python-3.x, quickfix

I am using quickfix python and trying to send a test request to the counterparty. When call the session_sendToTarget(req) function, it give me the error "Session not found".Can anyone tell me the reason behind it? What I am doing wrong?

Config:

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=60
FileStorePath=store
FileLogPath=client/log
StartTime=17:00:00
EndTime=17:02:00
UseDataDictionary=N
# DataDictionary=spec/FIX44.xml
# TransportDataDictionary=spec/FIX44.xml
# ValidateUserDefinedFields=N
SocketConnectHost=*****
SocketAcceptPort=****
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N
ResetOnLogout=N
ResetOnLogon=Y
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2

# standard config elements

[SESSION]
# inherit ConnectionType, ReconnectInterval and SenderCompID from default
BeginString=FIX.4.4
Symbol=APPL
SenderCompID=******
TargetCompID=******
SocketConnectHost=*****
SocketConnectPort=*****
HeartBtInt=30
```

Initiator.py

```
class Application(fix.Application):
    orderID = 0
    execID = 0

    def testrequest(self):
        req = fix44.TestRequest()
        req.setField(35, "A")
        req.setField(fix.RawData("data"))
        fix.Session_sendToTarget(req)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file = path
    settings = fix.SessionSettings(file)
    application = Application()
    storeFactory = fix.FileStoreFactory(settings)
    logFactory = fix.ScreenLogFactory(settings)
    initiator = fix.SocketInitiator(application, storeFactory, 
    settings, logFactory)
    initiator.start()

    while 1:
      session = initiator.getSessions()
      application.testrequest()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put in your [SESSION] config file the **SessionQualifier** attribute?

In my prod environment (written in c#) I've qualified every single session in the config file.

If you need some piece of code feel free to contact me.

```
[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.3
SenderCompID=FIX_STP_SENDER
TargetCompID=FIX_STP_PUBLISHER
StartTime=05:30:00
EndTime=21:45:00
UseLocalTime=N
SocketConnectPort=55555
SocketConnectHost=192.168.104.78
HeartBtInt=60
SessionQualifier=TRADESTP
UseDataDictionary=N
```

Also try to read this following question:
[Getting session not found error using quickfix python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54329354/getting-session-not-found-error-using-quickfix-python/54329940#54329940)

Comment: The Config file is already added in question. But I didn't add any session qualifier in my config file. Will you explain more about SessionQualifier?

Comment: A SessionQualifier can also be use to disambiguate otherwise identical sessions. (http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html).

Are you sure that your conterparty is live to listen at your fix message?

Comment: Will you please provide me a piece of a code where you add qualifier?

Comment: I suppose that the SessionQualifier tag is not mandatory if you have just one connection in your program. Please check if your ctp is listening your messages